# Redirect all existing routes and not founds to a single route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

my current ASP.net website needs to be taken down for a few hours and I wanted all current routes/pages to be sent to a "maintenance" page. I have a few ideas of how to do this but I feel like they are probably not the best solution. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file `App_Offline.htm` in the root directory of your application.
Whatever URL user requests, he will see this page.

You can just rename this file (`App_Offline.htm.online`) when you are finished.

According to [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff925031(v=vs.100).aspx):

> **To take a Web application offline before deployment**
>
> 1. Create a file called App_offline.htm and include a message in the file that lets users know that the site is unavailable because you are updating the site.
> 2. Place the App_offline.htm file in the root folder of the target Web site.
>
>    While the App_offline.htm file exists in the root of your Web site, any request to the Web site will redirect to that file.
>
>    When you have finished deploying the site, remove the App_offline.htm file.

Comment: Ok perfect! So all I have to do is write the App_Offline.htm in my root directory and then re-publish the site?

Comment: @TPN1994 Yeah, exactly. You create this file, web-site becomes offline. You publish your web-site and remove this file - web-site becomes online :)

Comment: Perfect, so putting back online is just a matter of deleting the file and republishing then, correct? :)

Comment: @TPN1994 Yes :) As easy as a light switch.